# Google Sheets - Index, Match formula from multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets

I got a problem with one fromula.

Two sheets:

- [1st Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sj7FlrO5ZbHkIUwtpkJdU3tokEBwEXRvyIpi6eVHig4/edit#gid=0)
- [2nd Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QGnFhtWaMUhvvFJFOXzX8UpzgRfkFLbF05F_tbWDrNU/edit#gid=0)

Look at formula on 2nd sheet B2

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Importrange("1sj7FlrO5ZbHkIUwtpkJdU3tokEBwEXRvyIpi6eVHig4","Sheet1!A:A"),
MATCH($A2,Importrange("1sj7FlrO5ZbHkIUwtpkJdU3tokEBwEXRvyIpi6eVHig4","Sheet1!B:B"), 0)), "Not ordered")
```

It is matching my status from 1st spreadsheet but only from B column. My question is how to add C column as well (add another match criteria). I want to have B and C together. Is it possible?

Thanks!

I've tried something like this but it is not working :

```
=INDEX("1sj7FlrO5ZbHkIUwtpkJdU3tokEBwEXRvyIpi6eVHig4","Sheet1!A:A"), MATCH($A2,Importrange("1sj7FlrO5ZbHkIUwtpkJdU3tokEBwEXRvyIpi6eVHig4","Sheet1!B:B"),
MATCH($A2,Importrange("1sj7FlrO5ZbHkIUwtpkJdU3tokEBwEXRvyIpi6eVHig4","Sheet1!C:C"), 0))
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're expecting as an outcome? It looks blank. Also be easier if you named sheets something less generic. You also have two columns with same name and only one record. Hard to figure out what you're looking for.

Comment: Hey, sorry. In "Spreadsheet 2" Column B I have one formula which is matching my order status from "Spreadsheet 1" when I put order number to column B "Spreadsheet 1" but this is working only when I put number to column B only, I want to add column C also. So when I place my order number to column B or C in "1 spreadsheet", status column in "Spreadsheet 2" should change (match) with status from "spreadsheet 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Importrange("1sj7FlrO5ZbHkIUwtpkJdU3tokEBwEXRvyIpi6eVHig4","Sheet1!A:A"),MATCH($A2,Importrange("1sj7FlrO5ZbHkIUwtpkJdU3tokEBwEXRvyIpi6eVHig4","Sheet1!B:B"), 0)), IFERROR(INDEX(Importrange("1sj7FlrO5ZbHkIUwtpkJdU3tokEBwEXRvyIpi6eVHig4","Sheet1!A:A"), MATCH($A2,Importrange("1sj7FlrO5ZbHkIUwtpkJdU3tokEBwEXRvyIpi6eVHig4","Sheet1!C:C"), 0)), "Not ordered"))
```

Try this! I joined a second exact formula as yours in the second parameter of the first IFERROR

Answer (score 0):

It'd probably be easier to just do a an `OR` statement. So something like this.

```
=If(Or(isnumber(firstcolumnLookupFormula),
  isnumber(SecondColumnLookupFormula)),"Ordered","Not Ordered").
```

You could do as many as needed then.